# HTML Image gallery with Dynamic with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display images on a page using the bootstrap grid system, where their names are dynamically created by taking it from a database. For example I have this database, and I want to use the imageID in the src name of each image. Is there any cleaner way to do it without having to manually add a new div etc for each image?

PHP Code for getting image id:

```
<?php
//dynamically render images

include "../storescripts/connect-mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imageGallery ORDER BY dateAdded ASC");
$images = array();
$imageCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the amount of products
if($imageCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $image = $row['imageID'];
        $images[] = $image;
}

}else{
    $image_gallery = "<h2>You have no images in the database</h2>";
}
?>
```

My HTML for displaying the images:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $images[0] ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $images[1] ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $images[2] ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $images[3] ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

See the image source for how I used the PHP.

Comment: So what`s wrong with putting that div in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have images available within `$images` array. So make a `foreach` loop inside html div.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $image; ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**Update**

This is for if you want only four divs inside a parent div over and over again.

```
<?php 

$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $image):
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">';
    echo '<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/' . $image .'" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>';
    echo '</div><!-- outputs child div -->';


    $i++;

    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo '</div> <!-- outputs parent div -->';
    }

endforeach;

if ($i % 4 != 0) {
    echo '</div> <!-- outputs parent div-->';
}
```

Comment: The only problem I had with this is that the images are not formatted correctly, as for every four images there are a new col-md-12 div is needed.

Comment: Hope, you can now do that dynamically instead of doing that manually. I mean 4 divs within a new col-md-12 div!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Use the code as follows

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php foreach($images as $image) {?>
          <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
               <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $image ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
          </div>
         <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding *div*s, you can simply use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php
        foreach($images as $image){
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 galleryImg">
                <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img onclick="myfunction(this)" class="galleryImage" src="../img/gallery/<?php echo $image; ?>.png" alt="Jedi Cycle Sport Gallery Image"></a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```